# Why doesn't devise related spec work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

First, let me say that login works correctly. The user is logged in for sure. I'm also certain that the post is happening properly (checked the messages and flushes, so i'm certain). And the real action of incrementing, as the test describes, works fine. Only the test fails.

But in this rspec below :

```
it "should increase the strength ability by one point and also update the strength_points by one if strength is the trained ability" do
    @user.str = 10
    @user.str_points = 0
    post :train_ability, :ability => 'str'
    flash[:error].should be_nil
    @user.str_points.should == 1
    @user.str.should == 11
end
```

The str and str_points shoulds fail. I'm actually using a login_user function in my macros(as specified in devise), like :

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = :user
      @user = Factory.create(:user)
      sign_in @user
    end
  end
end
```

I'm sure that @user is indeed the current_user, but it seems that any attribute changes do not really happen to @user inside the spec(:user is a factory i created).

Why doesn't this work ? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you haven't saved the `@user` before posting to `:train_ability`.
There's also a slim chance your `@user` may be cached after that so reloading it before your assertions could be necessary.

Try changing your spec to the following

```
it "should increase the strength ability by one point and also update the strength_points by one if strength is the trained ability" do
  @user.str = 10
  @user.str_points = 0
  @user.save! # save the @user object so str is 10 and str_points are 0
  post :train_ability, :ability => 'str'
  flash[:error].should be_nil
  @user.reload # reload the user in case str and str_points are cached
  @user.str_points.should == 1
  @user.str.should == 11
end
```